# Reference Entire Table with Cursor then Insert based on conditions

Tags: oracle, if-statement, plsql, cursor

If I am referencing an entire table with a cursor.  Can I use the insert statement based on conditions in other tables multiple times?  For example:

```
V_Name                 Emp.Name%type;
V_E_Number             Emp.Number%type;
V_Location             Emp.Location%type;
V_City                 Emp.City%type;
V_P_ID                 Emp.P_ID%type;
V_State_Code           Emp.State_Code%type;

Cursor C1 is Select emp.name, emp.number, emp.Location, emp.City, emp.P_ID, emp.State_Code
             From Employee Emp, Former_Employee Femp
             Where Emp.Number = Femp.Number
             And State_Code = '4';

Begin

Open C1;

Loop

Fetch C1 Into V_Name, V_E_Number, V_Location, V_City, V_P_ID, V_State_Code;

EXIT WHEN C1%NOTFOUND;

IF New_Emp.P_ID != V_P_ID 
Then Insert Into New_Emp
Values (V_Name, V_E_Number, V_Location, V_City, V_P_ID, V_State_Code); 

IF New_Emp.P_ID = V_P_ID,
   New_Emp.State_Code = V_State_Code
Then Insert Into Emp_Archive
VALUES (V_Name, V_E_Number, V_Location, V_City, V_P_ID, V_State_Code);  

Else Do Nothing;

End If;

End Loop;

Close C1;

End;
/
```

Then Can I open the cursor again and use another If Statement to populate a different table with different conditions?

Comment: Sounds like you're in a very good position to answer that yourself.  Have you attempted it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open a cursor, fetch from the cursor, close the cursor, and then re-open it later.  You may get different data when you open the cursor again because the data in the underlying table may have changed.  However, looking at your code, there seems to be no need to declare a cursor in the first place-- you can simply code two `INSERT` statements (assuming that the `new_emp` record that your code refers to but does not declare is valid)

```
INSERT INTO new_emp
  Select emp.name, emp.number, emp.Location, emp.City, emp.P_ID, emp.State_Code
    From Employee Emp, Former_Employee Femp
    Where Emp.Number = Femp.Number
      And State_Code = '4'
      AND emp.p_id   = new_emp.p_id;

INSERT INTO Emp_Archive
  Select emp.name, emp.number, emp.Location, emp.City, emp.P_ID, emp.State_Code
    From Employee Emp, Former_Employee Femp
    Where Emp.Number = Femp.Number
      And State_Code = '4'
      AND emp.p_id   = new_emp.p_id
      AND emp.state_code = new_emp.state_code;
```

You could simplify that further by doing a single INSERT ALL

```
INSERT ALL 
  WHEN new_emp.p_id = p_id
       THEN INTO new_emp( name, number, location, city, p_id, state_code )
              VALUES( name, number, location, city, p_id, state_code )
  WHEN new_emp.p_id = p_id AND
       new_emp.state_code = state_code
       THEN INTO emp_archive( name, number, location, city, p_id, state_code )
              VALUES( name, number, location, city, p_id, state_code )
  Select emp.name, emp.number, emp.Location, emp.City, emp.P_ID, emp.State_Code
    From Employee Emp, Former_Employee Femp
    Where Emp.Number = Femp.Number
      And State_Code = '4'
```

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to learn pl/sql.  Your reply was very helpful!